# Display a form field according to the selected value in a drop-down list Angular TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, typescript

I want to display a form field according to the selected value in a drop-down list of the form.

For example if the element selected in the dropdown list is 'first' I want the form does not change.

On the other hand if I choose the element 'two' in my drop-down list I want it to display the input 'appears'

Here is my code for the moment

HTML:

```
<div class="div-champs">
    <p id="champs">Type
       <span id="required">*</span>
    </p>
    <div class="select-style ">
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="type" > 
           <option style="display:none">
           <option *ngFor="let o of options">
              {{o.name}}
           </option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>

<p id="champs">Appears
    <input type="appears" class="form-control" name="appears" formControlName="appears">
</p>
```

TypeScript:

```
   ...
private selectedOption: string;

options = [
  { name: "first", value: 1 },
  { name: "two", value: 2 }
]
  ...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Beautiful day,

Regards,
Valentin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can put `if` condition as -

```
<p id="champs" *ngIf="selectedOption == 'two'">Appears
    <input type="appears" class="form-control" name="appears" formControlName="appears">
</p>
```

### html

```
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="type" > 
           <option style="display:none">
           <option [value]="o.name" *ngFor="let o of options">
              {{o.name}}
           </option>
       </select>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqkfyx

Note : It looks like you pretty new to the Angular, I would encourage to walk through Angular tutorial. Stackoverflow will not be helpful in long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I did not know ngIf and it is true that it corresponds exactly to my problem. I follow a tutorial angular but I have not seen all the parameters yet. However your code me to be fair but it does not run. The appears does not appear. If you have an idea ... I continue my research :)

Comment: You had forgotten `[value]` in `option`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw your change but it does not work. I think he can not recover the value of the drop-down list. I continue my research with console.log and alert. Once resolved I put the answer and your post resolved

Comment: My bad. its should be `[value]="o.name"`

Comment: Thanks, i just made the change but still not ^^

Comment: OMG, I should work. Here is the sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqkfyx. Note I had removed `formControlName` from `input`.

Comment: Ahah thank you very much. I'm looking at it right away. I have two errors in my console I will also study them:
1- ERROR Error:
      ngModel can not be used to register with a parent formGroup directive. Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead. Example: ...
2- ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {...}, nodeIndex: 138, nodeDef: {...}, elDef: {...}, elView: {...}} ...

Comment: I want to clarify that I am on Angular (5) and not AngularJs

Comment: Yes, I know that you are in Angular 2+ not AngularJS

Comment: I will be able to help you if you can share more code of yours.

Comment: I put it in resolved. I'm going to look at this from my side and bring the problem in comment. thank you so much

Comment: I have so much code that I do not know what else I could share. Especially that you send me a link or the solution works and that I implode in my code and that it does not work. I'm looking at this, I'm coming back to you

Comment: the problem is that my ngIf is in a ngSubmit. Thus the display of the new field can not be done because it is "blocked" by the ngSubmit

Answer (score 3):

You can use an angular if contidition in the html, it's called *ngIf.

```
<input *ngIf="selectedOption == 'two'" type="appears" class="form-control" name="appears" formControlName="appears">
```

Source: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply ! Indeed it seems to me just like the code above but it does not run when I select 'two' Appears does not appear. I think he can not recover the value of the drop-down list. I continue my research thank you :)